# Код при переносе из codepen перестает работать

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Когда я переношу отсюда https://codepen.io/joshsorosky/pen/gaaBoB код в файлы, он перестает работать. Ничего не изменяю при его переносе. Он не работает, если его переносить в свой codepen.
Перестают работать анимации перехода между sign in/ sign up и после нажатия кнопки входа

'''

```
    <div class="container">
     <div class="frame">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul class"links">
       <li class="signin-active"><a class="btn">Sign in</a></li>
    <li class="signup-inactive"><a class="btn">Sign up </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
                    <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post" name="form">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="username" placeholder=""/>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="password" placeholder=""/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
      <label for="checkbox" ><span class="ui"></span>Keep me signed in</label>
      <div class="btn-animate">
        <a class="btn-signin">Sign in</a>
      </div>
                    </form>
    
                    <form class="form-signup" action="" method="post" name="form">
      <label for="fullname">Full name</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder=""/>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="email" placeholder=""/>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="password" placeholder=""/>
      <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm password</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="confirmpassword" placeholder=""/>
      <a ng-click="checked = !checked" class="btn-signup">Sign Up</a>
                    </form>
  
        <div  class="success">
          <svg width="270" height="270" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 60 60" id="check" ng-class="checked ? 'checked' : ''">
             <path fill="#ffffff" d="M40.61,23.03L26.67,36.97L13.495,23.788c-1.146-1.147-1.359-2.936-0.504-4.314
              c3.894-6.28,11.169-10.243,19.283-9.348c9.258,1.021,16.694,8.542,17.622,17.81c1.232,12.295-8.683,22.607-20.849,22.042
              c-9.9-0.46-18.128-8.344-18.972-18.218c-0.292-3.416,0.276-6.673,1.51-9.578" />
            <div class="successtext">
               <p> Thanks for signing up! Check your email for confirmation.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="forgot">
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="cover-photo"></div>
    <div class="profile-photo"></div>
    <h1 class="welcome">Welcome, Chris</h1>
    <a class="btn-goback" value="Refresh" onClick="history.go()">Go back</a>
  </div>
```

'''

Comment: А настроки `JS` у вас [такие](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXEi5.png)? Так же проверьте другие настройки

Comment: @EzioMercer, в codepen он сработал, а как быть с файлом? Я получается вставил это в head <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> , но оно не заработало.

Comment: А в чём ошибка?

Comment: @EzioMercer, код все равно не работает

Comment: В чём ошибки? Что пишется в консоли? Нужны конкретные детали, что идёт не так. Мы не можем просто гадать в чём проблема

Comment: @EzioMercer, https://disk.yandex.ru/i/8CgAswwrtz5ttg только это

Comment: И причём тут ошибки сервера? Это вообще к делу не относится, проблема в другом

Comment: @EzioMercer, в консоли кроме этого ничего нет

Comment: У вас ошибка не в коде из `codepen`, а в другом. Так что ищите что у вас вызывает эти ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скопипасить себе то что тут (не добавлял ангуляр):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".form-signin").toggleClass("form-signin-left");
    $(".form-signup").toggleClass("form-signup-left");
    $(".frame").toggleClass("frame-long");
    $(".signup-inactive").toggleClass("signup-active");
    $(".signin-active").toggleClass("signin-inactive");
    $(".forgot").toggleClass("forgot-left");
    $(this).removeClass("idle").addClass("active");
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".btn-signup").click(function() {
    $(".nav").toggleClass("nav-up");
    $(".form-signup-left").toggleClass("form-signup-down");
    $(".success").toggleClass("success-left");
    $(".frame").toggleClass("frame-short");
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".btn-signin").click(function() {
    $(".btn-animate").toggleClass("btn-animate-grow");
    $(".welcome").toggleClass("welcome-left");
    $(".cover-photo").toggleClass("cover-photo-down");
    $(".frame").toggleClass("frame-short");
    $(".profile-photo").toggleClass("profile-photo-down");
    $(".btn-goback").toggleClass("btn-goback-up");
    $(".forgot").toggleClass("forgot-fade");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(246, 247, 249, 0.8), rgba(246, 247, 249, 0.8)), url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22006283/preview/codepen/sky-clouds-cloudy-mountain.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.frame {
  height: 575px;
  width: 430px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.75), rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.95)), url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22006283/preview/codepen/clouds-cloudy-forest-mountain.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.frame-long {
  height: 615px;
}

.frame-short {
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.nav-up {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  opacity: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.signin-active a {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #1059FF;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.signin-inactive a {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.signup-active a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #1059FF;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.signup-inactive a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 430px;
  height: 375px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 37px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  padding-top: 55px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease, transform .5s ease;
}

.form-signin-left {
  transform: translateX(-400px);
  opacity: .0;
}

.form-signup {
  width: 430px;
  height: 375px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 37px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  padding-top: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: -375px;
  left: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.form-signup-left {
  transform: translateX(-399px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-signup-down {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.success {
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -890px;
  left: 450px;
  opacity: .0;
  transition: all .8s .4s ease;
}

.success-left {
  transform: translateX(-406px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.successtext {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: -35px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  padding-right: 37px;
}

#check path {
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: .85px;
  stroke-dasharray: 60px 300px;
  stroke-dashoffset: -166px;
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s ease .5s, fill 1.5s ease 1.0s;
}

#check.checked path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 33px;
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, .03);
}

.form-signin input,
.form-signup input {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.form-styling {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  display: block;
}

:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form-signin input:focus,
textarea:focus,
.form-signup input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  border: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: background .5s ease;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 85px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  width: 65px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-radius: 15px;
  left: 0;
  top: -3px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 7px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}


/* on checked */

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  background: #0F4FE6;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 7px;
  left: 45px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .ui,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label .ui:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .ui:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label .ui:before {
  content: "no";
  left: 32px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .ui:after {
  content: "yes";
  color: #ffffff;
}

[type="checkbox"]:focus+label:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.btn-signup {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  background-color: #1059FF;
}

.btn-signin {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.btn-animate {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 89, 255, 1);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all .5s ease, top .5s ease .5s, height .5s ease .5s, background-color .5s ease .75s;
}

.btn-animate-grow {
  width: 130%;
  height: 625px;
  position: relative;
  left: -55px;
  top: -420px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a.btn-signup:hover,
a.btn-signin:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0F4FE6;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.forgot {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 24px;
  margin-top: -535px;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.forgot-left {
  transform: translateX(-400px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.forgot-fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.forgot a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.75);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease .25s, opacity .1s ease 1s;
}

.welcome-left {
  transform: translateY(-780px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.cover-photo {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -900px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.75), rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.95)), url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22006283/preview/codepen/landscape-nature-man-person.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1.5s ease 0.55s;
}

.cover-photo-down {
  top: -575px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.profile-photo {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 70px;
  left: 155px;
  top: -1000px;
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22006283/preview/codepen/nature-water-rocks-hiking.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 135%;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1.5s ease 0.35s, opacity .75s ease .5s;
  border: solid 3px #ffffff;
}

.profile-photo-down {
  top: -636px;
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-goback {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: -400px;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 83%;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-right: 37px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1059FF;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border: solid 1px #1059FF;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1.5s ease 0.35s, opacity .75s ease .5s;
}

.btn-goback-up {
  top: -1080px;
  opacity: 1;
}

a.btn-goback:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0F4FE6;
  transition: all .5s;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* refresh button styling */

#refresh {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 13px 0 0 13px;
}

.refreshicon {
  fill: #d3d3d3;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: fill .25s ease, transform .25s ease;
}

.refreshicon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #1059FF;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="container">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class "links">
        <li class="signin-active"><a class="btn">Sign in</a></li>
        <li class="signup-inactive"><a class="btn">Sign up </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
      <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post" name="form">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="username" placeholder="" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="password" placeholder="" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox"><span class="ui"></span>Keep me signed in</label>
        <div class="btn-animate">
          <a class="btn-signin">Sign in</a>
        </div>
      </form>

      <form class="form-signup" action="" method="post" name="form">
        <label for="fullname">Full name</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="email" placeholder="" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="password" placeholder="" />
        <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm password</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="" />
        <a ng-click="checked = !checked" class="btn-signup">Sign Up</a>
      </form>

      <div class="success">
        <svg width="270" height="270" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 60 60" id="check" ng-class="checked ? 'checked' : ''">
                 <path fill="#ffffff" d="M40.61,23.03L26.67,36.97L13.495,23.788c-1.146-1.147-1.359-2.936-0.504-4.314
                  c3.894-6.28,11.169-10.243,19.283-9.348c9.258,1.021,16.694,8.542,17.622,17.81c1.232,12.295-8.683,22.607-20.849,22.042
                  c-9.9-0.46-18.128-8.344-18.972-18.218c-0.292-3.416,0.276-6.673,1.51-9.578" />
                <div class="successtext">
                   <p> Thanks for signing up! Check your email for confirmation.</p>
                </div>
             </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="forgot">
        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <div class="cover-photo"></div>
        <div class="profile-photo"></div>
        <h1 class="welcome">Welcome, Chris</h1>
        <a class="btn-goback" value="Refresh" onClick="history.go()">Go back</a>
      </div>
  </div>
    
  <a id="refresh" value="Refresh" onClick="history.go()">
    <svg class="refreshicon"   version="1.1" id="Capa_1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 322.447 322.447" style="enable-background:new 0 0 322.447 322.447;"
         xml:space="preserve">
         <path  d="M321.832,230.327c-2.133-6.565-9.184-10.154-15.75-8.025l-16.254,5.281C299.785,206.991,305,184.347,305,161.224
                c0-84.089-68.41-152.5-152.5-152.5C68.411,8.724,0,77.135,0,161.224s68.411,152.5,152.5,152.5c6.903,0,12.5-5.597,12.5-12.5
                c0-6.902-5.597-12.5-12.5-12.5c-70.304,0-127.5-57.195-127.5-127.5c0-70.304,57.196-127.5,127.5-127.5
                c70.305,0,127.5,57.196,127.5,127.5c0,19.372-4.371,38.337-12.723,55.568l-5.553-17.096c-2.133-6.564-9.186-10.156-15.75-8.025
                c-6.566,2.134-10.16,9.186-8.027,15.751l14.74,45.368c1.715,5.283,6.615,8.642,11.885,8.642c1.279,0,2.582-0.198,3.865-0.614
                l45.369-14.738C320.371,243.946,323.965,236.895,321.832,230.327z"/>
    </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Не работает он у меня